# MySQL Query Improvement/Optimisation - Insert Row Without Conflicts

Tags: mysql

I am having problems with table locking in my little app and want to know how I can improve my query.

Below is the relevant table information.

```
| assigned_presents | CREATE TABLE `assigned_presents` (
  `id` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `recipient_id` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `present_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `recipient_id_index` (`recipient_id`),
  KEY `present_id` (`present_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_message` FOREIGN KEY (`recipient_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12914 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

| present | CREATE TABLE `present` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `present_type_id` (`present`,`type_id`),
  KEY `index_type_id` (`type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=83196627 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

| person | CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  KEY `added_index` (`added`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=249486846 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

And this is my current query.  It does the job but I'm wondering if it could be improved.

```
INSERT INTO assigned_presents (present_id, recipient_id) 
SELECT present.id, ${person_id} FROM present WHERE present.type_id IN (""" + ${present_type_options} + """)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT present_id FROM assigned_presents WHERE assigned_present.present_id=present.id)
ORDER BY present.id LIMIT 1
```

It is basically assigning a present of a particular type (`${present_type_options}`) to a person (`${person_id}`) but making sure that present hasn't already been assigned.  I hope it makes sense.

I basically want to insert a `present_id` and `person_id` into `assigned_presents` as long as the `present_id` doesn't already exist in the table.

The query makes sense to me but I am not an experienced MySQL user.  I do see that there may be row locking issues when called under heavy load (I haven't figured out how to stress test it) due to the query relying on two select queries before the insert.

The error I get is:

```
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Also, I can't retry the query.  It HAS to work the first time it is called.  The reason for this is that this is a first in first served type API where responses are immediate.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: *What* problem do you have with rowlocking? Do you keep a transaction open after that? Which rows are locked will depend on your indexes, so check them/add them to your question. Your query is not safe with default settings, you will need to use serializable isolation (which will actually increase your locking a lot, so specify your locking problem). The safe choice is obviously to add a unique key and retry on failure. I think you will have to find good arguments why you "can't retry the query" - as there can be other errors too, e.g. connection issues, which you have to handle anyway.

Comment: @Solarflare I have added more information.  I found out that there used to be retrying (I took over from someone else) but there were many problems with the API taking too long to respond and many complaints about people who registered for gifts first who missed out while others who registered afterwards, received presents.  The whole design is a mess and we are looking at rebuilding a lot of it but this part in particular is on a shortish time constraint and it is a volunteering project so resources are a little thin.

Comment: Thanks for the table statements, it helps a lot to understand what you are doing. To understand deadlocks, the code of the whole transaction is relevant (as other parts of that transaction can lock as well). Two things: a) a person can only get one present at all, right? b) there is a design improvement: add the `recipient_id`-column (and the rest) to the `present` table and remove the `assigned` table. Then, every present can only be assigned once *by design*. It simplifies your query (update the first row where `recipient_id` is `null`). Is such a change possible?

Comment: Also about the not-repeating part: The code (in the api?) that executes this query will have to check for errors and then handle that error if you get an error (e.g. a deadlock, connection loss or a potential duplicate key violation), e.g. by repeating the query. That is the bare minimum of literally every code that uses a database. So I am still not sure what you mean by not being able to repeat the query. Also: I'm not sure how you ensure that there are actually enough presents available (e.g. 5 presents, 6 people press "send gift"), which would be a logical error you need to handle too.

Comment: Yes, the design is terrible.  It is something I am planning to improve.  The job is a little big though so am just hoping to fix this SQL as an 'intermediate' solution.  Also, a person CAN get more than one present.  They give out presents every month like a lolly scramble of sorts.

Comment: I am pretty certain that `UNIQUE KEY recipient_id_index (recipient_id)` will prevent any person to get assigned two presents. Anyway: The design is not terrible. It is technically correct (and might have a reason), just inefficient for this specific case. But you can do it differently too (e.g., as mentioned: have a unique key; select a present id, insert, if it fails repeat). But again: a deadlock will depend on the complete transaction (and all other transactions), so we cannot say that without seeing more code and where transactions start. How many presents are given at a certain moment?